# Enforcing horizontal node ordering in a .dot tree

Tags: binary-tree, graphviz, dot

I am trying to recreate an example diagram for a binary search tree with GraphViz. This is how it should look in the end:

[image]

This is my first attempt:

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.3;
    ranksep=0.2;
    margin=0.1;
    node [shape=circle];
    edge [arrowsize=0.8];
    6 -> 4;
    6 -> 11;
    4 -> 2;
    4 -> 5;
    2 -> 1;
    2 -> 3;
    11 -> 8;
    11 -> 14;
    8 -> 7;
    8 -> 10;
    10 -> 9;
    14 -> 13;
    14 -> 16;
    13 -> 12;
    16 -> 15;
    16 -> 17;
}
```

But unfortunately GraphViz doesn't care about the horizontal positions of the tree, so I get:

[image]

How can I add constraints so that the horizontal positions of the vertices reflects their total ordering?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could follow the usual approach of adding invisible nodes and invisible edges, and playing with edge weight etc. as proposed on the [graphviz FAQ about balanced trees](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-get-trees-more-balanced/966). In some [simple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3105923/63733), this is enough.

But there is a better solution: Graphviz comes with a tool called **gvpr** (*graph pattern scanning and processing language*) which allows to

> copy input graphs to its output, possibly transforming their structure and attributes, creating new graphs, or printing arbitrary information

And since [Emden R. Gansner did all the work already by creating a script which does layout nicely binary trees](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2010q2/007101.html), heres how to to that (all credit goes to ERG):

Save the following gvpr script into a file called `tree.gv` :

```
BEGIN {
  double tw[node_t];    // width of tree rooted at node
  double nw[node_t];    // width of node
  double xoff[node_t];  // x offset of root from left side of its tree
  double sp = 36;       // extra space between left and right subtrees
  double wd, w, w1, w2; 
  double x, y, z;
  edge_t e1, e2;
  node_t n;
}
BEG_G {
  $.bb = "";
  $tvtype=TV_postfwd;   // visit root after all children visited
}
N {
  sscanf ($.width, "%f", &w);
  w *= 72;  // convert inches to points
  nw[$] = w;
  if ($.outdegree == 0) {
    tw[$] = w;
    xoff[$] = w/2.0;
  }
  else if ($.outdegree == 1) {
    e1 = fstout($);
    w1 = tw[e1.head];    
    tw[$] = w1 + (sp+w)/2.0;
    if (e1.side == "left")
      xoff[$] = tw[$] - w/2.0;
    else
      xoff[$] = w/2.0;
  }
  else {
    e1 = fstout($);
    w1 = tw[e1.head];    
    e2 = nxtout(e1);
    w2 = tw[e2.head];    
    wd = w1 + w2 + sp;
    if (w > wd)
      wd = w;
    tw[$] = wd;
    xoff[$] = w1 + sp/2.0;
  }
}
BEG_G {
  $tvtype=TV_fwd;   // visit root first, then children
}
N {
  if ($.indegree == 0) {
    sscanf ($.pos, "%f,%f", &x, &y);
    $.pos = sprintf("0,%f", y);
  }
  if ($.outdegree == 0) return;
  sscanf ($.pos, "%f,%f", &x, &y);
  wd = tw[$];
  e1 = fstout($);
  n = e1.head;
  sscanf (n.pos, "%f,%f", &z, &y);
  if ($.outdegree == 1) {
    if (e1.side == "left")
      n.pos = sprintf("%f,%f",  x - tw[n] - sp/2.0 + xoff[n], y);
    else
      n.pos = sprintf("%f,%f", x + sp/2.0 + xoff[n], y);
  }
  else {
    n.pos = sprintf("%f,%f", x - tw[n] - sp/2.0 + xoff[n], y);
    e2 = nxtout(e1);
    n = e2.head;
    sscanf (n.pos, "%f,%f", &z, &y);
    n.pos = sprintf("%f,%f", x + sp/2.0 + xoff[n], y);
  }
}
```

Assuming your dot file containing the graph is called `binarytree.gv`, you may execute the following line:

```
dot binarytree.gv | gvpr -c -ftree.gv | neato -n -Tpng -o binarytree.png
```

The result is:

[image: Binary tree nicely layouted with graphiv and a gvpr script thanks to Emden R. Gansner]

By switching around a line or two in the script, you'll even get to have the single child nodes go to the left instead of the right side.

Comment: I am trying, but I only get `gvpr: "./tree.gv", line 46: _nd_a0:<<< -- syntax error` (I verified that the code got copied properly, also tried to copy from the Gansner post). Now I have no clue what that is supposed to mean? I see nothing suspicious in line 46 :-(

Comment: It is the last `N { }` block somehow, if I remove that the error disappears, but also the layout is not done. Might this be a version problem? I have `gvpr version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)`

Comment: I used 2.28.0, and it worked right away. Gansner's post was made about 6 months after your graphviz version was released, so I'd try with a more recent version.

Comment: Indeed, I updated to GraphViz 2.28.0, and the script runs -- Fantastic, thanks so much!

Comment: When the tree above is a binary tree the nodes 9, 12 should be drawn to  the left of their parents. Can I do this with the tree.gv script?

Comment: @MartenBauer Yes, you'll just have to switch a line or two in the script.