# python networkx change angle of outgoing edge in DiGraph

Tags: python, networkx, angle, edges

I converted a newick tree with Phylo into a networkx graph. The tree is rooted, therefore it is a DiGraph.

```
langTree = Phylo.read('output/world-NWPV-languageTreeForSample-TDist.nwk', 'newick')
#print langTree
langTree.rooted = True
langNet = Phylo.to_networkx(langTree)

return langNet
```

I use a simple method for drawing the graph.

```
langNet = networkx.DiGraph()
langNet = createLTGraph()

pos = networkx.graphviz_layout(langNet, prog='dot', args='-Nfontsize=10 -Nwidth=".5" -   
Nheight=".5" -Nmargin=0 -Gfontsize=8')
networkx.draw(langNet, pos)
A = networkx.to_agraph(langNet)
A.layout('dot', args='-Nfontsize=10 -Nwidth=".5" -Nheight=".5" -Nmargin=0 
-Gfontsize=8')
A.draw('test2.png')

plt.show()
```

The result I get is:
[image]

What I actually want is something like this:
[image]

I thought it might be possible to change the angle of the outcoming endges with an attribute in the layout part. But I can't figure out how to do it.
It there a possiblity to change the angle?

Thanks,
M

Comment: Graphviz isn't designed for drawing trees but maybe this SO question can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902745/enforcing-horizontal-node-ordering-in-a-dot-tree

Comment: I know it isn't designed for trees, but additionally, I need to add some nodes and draw a network out of it. This tree should serve as an underlying image.
Thanks for the page, I will try it :)