# How to print a BST from any given array in any order with DOT language and Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree, dot

I am given an array of integers like this: [56,200,213,96, {}, {},...] and Im asked to print a BST (binary search tree) using DOT. For any array given the root will be the position 0 of the array, arr[0]. This should be developed using Eclipse.

However, my confusion about this particular task is how to make this algorithm in Java and then use the DOT language to "draw" the tree? Or should it be directly done with DOT? Maybe im approaching the task with the wrong perspective.

Ive done research about BST, the different types of orders and the node structure to compare numbers and insert them to "make" the tree and I already know how to handle Eclipse and Java.

//Part of my node structure for the BST algorithm

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        right = null;
        left = null;
    }
}
```

Below an example of the output for any given array:
[image: BST]

Comment: `Or should it be directly done with DOT?` Yes

Comment: See: [How do I make a dot graph representing a binary tree more symmetric?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23430742/1243762)

Comment: Don't be surprised if this gets closed as a duplicate.

Comment: From what you've said, my understanding is that your task is to write a Java program that (1) constructs the tree using your Node class,  then (2) outputs that tree using DOT format (so probably to a `.gv` file looking like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)#Directed_graphs )