# Graphviz: more space between node

Tags: binary-tree, graphviz, dot, treenode

I'm trying to create binary trees using the Graphviz tool but not as I would like.
For example: I would like to draw this tree:

[image]

With Graphviz I managed to do this:

[image]

In principle is fine but I would like that the nodes were arranged as the sample image. There is more space between nodes brothers.. I wish every time a parent node generates a son (though only child), the latter is or left or right of the father, and not in the middle.

Then I would like that the arrows are more subtle.

Searching the internet I could not find how to change the layout of the nodes nor how to make thinner arrows. I only found how to change the shape of the arrow but it is not what interests me.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enforcing horizontal node ordering in a .dot tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902745/enforcing-horizontal-node-ordering-in-a-dot-tree)

Comment: Check out the question marked as duplicate - it contains a solution which will pretty-print binary trees.

Comment: @marapet I'm so sorry. Thanks!

Comment: No need to be sorry - just upvote the linked answer if it's useful to you :)