# Side-by-side binary trees in GraphViz

Tags: tree, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to format 2 (or ideally N) disconnected binary trees side-by-side, and I want the formatting to be "proper" for a binary tree, roughly like so:

[image]

Even if some nodes are missing, the rest should stay exactly where they are.

I generated an approximation of this balancing for one tree with a script called `tree.gv` from [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905657/1556416):

```
dot one_tree.dot | gvpr -c -f tree.gv | neato -n -Tpdf -o tree.pdf
```

It's not perfectly balanced the way I would like, but it's very workable.
[image]

**Now I want multiple trees side by side**. Here's what I've tried:

```
dot trees.dot | neato -n -Goverlap=false -Tpdf -o tree.pdf
```

Properly side-by-side, but the bottom black leaves should be splayed right, leaving room for their missing siblings.
[image]

```
dot trees.dot | gvpr -c -f tree.gv | neato -n -Tpdf -o tree.pdf
```

Each tree is properly formatted, but they overlap.
[image]

Surely combining the two will work?

```
dot trees.dot | gvpr -c -f tree.gv | neato -n -Goverlap=false -Tpdf -o tree.pdf
```

[image]

Here is `trees.dot`:

```
digraph BST {
    graph [center=true, margin=0.01, nodesep=0.1, ranksep=0.3, width=1,ratio=.25];
    node [fontname="Arial",style=filled,color="0.0 0.0 0.0",fixedsize=true,width=0.15,shape=circle,label=""];
    node [margin=0.01,fillcolor="lightgrey"];
    edge [dir=none];
    node [fillcolor="black"];
    Lower;
    Lower -> LowerR;
    Lower -> LowerL;
    LowerL -> LowerLR;
    LowerR -> LowerRR;
    node [fillcolor="red"];
    Upper;
    Upper -> UpperR;
    Upper -> UpperL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main trick to form trees is to use an extra invisible node with high edge weight that is then placed directly below the parent node. The order of appearence counts.

```
digraph BST {
    graph [center=true, margin=0.01, nodesep=0.1, ranksep=0.3, width=1,ratio=.25];
    node [fontname="Arial",style=filled,color="0.0 0.0 0.0",fixedsize=true,width=0.15,shape=circle,label=""];
    node [margin=0.01,fillcolor="lightgrey"];
    edge [dir=none];
    node [fillcolor="black"];
    Lower;
    LowerL;
    LowerM [style=invis];
    LowerR;
    Lower -> LowerR;
    Lower -> LowerM [weight=100 style=invis];
    Lower -> LowerL;
    LowerLM [style=invis];
    LowerLR;
    LowerRM [style=invis];
    LowerRR;
    LowerL -> LowerLR;
    LowerL -> LowerLM [weight=100 style=invis];
    LowerR -> LowerRR;
    LowerR -> LowerRM [weight=100 style=invis];
    node [fillcolor="red"];
    Upper;
    UpperR;
    UpperM [style=invis];
    UpperL;
    Upper -> UpperR;
    Upper -> UpperM [weight=100 style=invis];
    Upper -> UpperL;
}
```

[image]

To prevent independent trees or tree branches from horizontal overlapping you have to use clusters (see my answer to [Making graphviz trees have parents centred above children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859384/making-graphviz-trees-have-parents-centred-above-children))

```
digraph BST {
    graph [center=true, margin=0.01, nodesep=0.1, ranksep=0.3, width=1,ratio=.25];
    node [fontname="Arial",style=filled,color="0.0 0.0 0.0",fixedsize=true,width=0.15,shape=circle,label=""];
    node [margin=0.01,fillcolor="lightgrey"];
    edge [dir=none];
    node [fillcolor="black"];
    graph [style=invis];
    subgraph cluster_Lower {
        Lower;
        LowerL;
        LowerM [style=invis];
        LowerR;
        Lower -> LowerR;
        Lower -> LowerM [weight=100 style=invis];
        Lower -> LowerL;
        LowerLM [style=invis];
        LowerLR;
        LowerRM [style=invis];
        LowerRR;
        LowerL -> LowerLR;
        LowerL -> LowerLM [weight=100 style=invis];
        LowerR -> LowerRR;
        LowerR -> LowerRM [weight=100 style=invis];
    }
    node [fillcolor="red"];
    subgraph cluster_Upper {
        Upper;
        UpperR;
        UpperM [style=invis];
        UpperL;
        Upper -> UpperR;
        Upper -> UpperM [weight=100 style=invis];
        Upper -> UpperL;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is guiding me on my way. I would still like the tree to look balanced (updated question with the desired picture). In your left tree, the two bottom-most nodes should be shifted to the left a bit. If I figure out an exact sequence, I will post it here.